# Handling Multiple IDs In A Single jQuery Statement

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've tried searching the site, but am really struggling to find what I want... Basically I have some jQuery code that checks the state of three IDs, they are tied to three checkboxes;

```
$('#submitButton').click(function(){
    if($("#cb1,#cb2,#cb3").is(':checked'))
        return true;
    else
        return false;
});
```

How would I restructure this jQuery statement to make it so that all three checkboxes have to be CHECKED? At the moment, either one can be checked for the action to be performed

I'm betting there is a really simple solution to all of this, but I have been lpooking at it for so long, I just can't see it. Could someone with a fresh pair of eyes and a less addled brain please steer me in the right direction?

Comment: Felix fixed it. Thank matey, here a FIDDLE of the working code for anyone else who might require it ;)  [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/takuhii/5zndt/)

Comment: Please check this: http://jsfiddle.net/mahavir4dev/Z93Y5/  This will work for any number of checkboxes.

Comment: Many thanks my friend, that is immensely helpful ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use:

```
$('#submitButton').click(function(){
    if ($('#cb1').is(':checked') && $('#cb1').is(':checked') && $('#cb3').is(':checked')) {
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
});
```

Comment: Ace!! You sir are a legend. Forgive my stupidity, but what does the && mean?

Comment: @Daren `&&` in javascript means `Logical AND`. You can read more on the logical operators [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_Operators). Glad it helped :)

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
if($("#cb1").is(':checked') && $("#cb2").is(':checked') && $("#cb3").is(':checked'))
```

---

`$("#cb1,#cb2,#cb3").is(':checked')` will return result for the 1st element only

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
$('#submitButton').click(function(){
    if($("#cb1:checked,#cb2:checked,#cb3:checked").length === 3)
        return true;
    else
        return false;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
 if ($('#cb1:checked,#cb2:checked,#cb3:checked').length == 3) {
   //all three are checked.do something
 }
```

or

```
 if ($('#cb1:checked,#cb2:checked,#cb3:checked').length == $('#cb1,#cb2,#cb3').length) {
   //all three are checked.do something
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try:

```
$('#submitButton').click(function(){
    if($('#cb1')[0].checked && $('#cb2')[0].checked && $('#cb3')[0].checked)return true;
    return false;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just add a class to your checkboxes and use like so:

```
$('#submitButton').click(function(){
    if($(".myCheckbox:checked").length == 3) {
        console.log('true');
    }
    else {
        console.log('false');
    }
});
```

Here is the JSFiddle Example:

http://jsfiddle.net/cLH8s/1/